# Redux: TypeError: e is undefined

Tags: redux

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/3017

**Problem: Occurs when I wrap my action creator with a dispatch in the container area where I utilize the connect method--I followed the style from redux documentation.**

I am utilizing redux, and redux thunk. I am attempting to create a login action, so far it does not work when I dispatch an action, which dispatch's an another one.

LoginContainer.js

```
import CONFIG from "../../../config";

import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import {authenticateUser} from "../../../actions/authenticateUser";

import Login from '../../../components/views/login/Login'

import {store} from '../../../store';

function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let calpersId = parseInt(e.target[0].value || e.target[1].value, 10) || 0;
    store.dispatch(authenticateUser(calpersId))
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        authentication: state.authentication
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        handleSubmit: (e) => {dispatch(handleSubmit(e))}
    }
}

const LoginContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);

export default LoginContainer;
```

authenticateUser.action.js

```
import CONFIG from '../config'

export const AUTHENTICATE_USER = 'AUTHENTICATE_USER'

export const initiateUserAuthentication = (token) => ({
    type: AUTHENTICATE_USER,
    token
})

export const AUTHENTICATATION_SUCCEEDED = 'AUTHENTICATATION_SUCCEEDED'

export const authenticatationSucceeded = (payload) => ({
    type: AUTHENTICATE_USER,
    payload
})


export const USER_ID_DOES_NOT_EXIST = 'USER_ID_DOES_NOT_EXIST'

export const userIdDoesNotExist = (uid) => ({
    type: USER_ID_DOES_NOT_EXIST,
    uid,
    message: "User id does not exist"
})

export function authenticateUser(id) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        let guidMap = {
            7103503579: "dad08fde-0ac1-404a-ba8a-cc7c76d5810f",
            6632408185: "6632408185-guid",
            6581985123: "6581985123-guid",
            1226290314: "a3908aa7-c142-4752-85ea-3741cf28f75e",
            4618604679: "4618604679-guid",
            6452522440: "6452522440-guid",
            3685610572: "3685610572-guid",
            5564535492: "5564535492-guid",
            5600493427: "5600493427-guid",
            3996179678: "3996179678-guid",
            7302651964: "7302651964-guid",
            3148148090: "3148148090-guid",
            5826752269: "5826752269-guid",
            6827859055: "6827859055-guid",
            1677401305: "1677401305-guid",
            2640602392: "dbed1af6-0fc9-45dc-96a3-ab15aa05a7a2",
            6474994805: "6474994805-guid"
        };
        let guid = guidMap[id]
        return fetch(CONFIG.API.MY_CALPERS_SERVER.LOCATION + 'ept/development/rest/simulatedAuth.json?guid=' + guid, {
            credentials: 'include'
        })
            .then(
                response => response.json(),
                error => console.log('An error occured.', error))
            .then(json => {
                document.cookie = "authentication=" + guid + "; max-age=" + (60 * 30);
                dispatch(authenticatationSucceeded(json))
            })
    }
}
```

authenticateUser.reducer.js

```
import {AUTHENTICATE_USER, AUTHENTICATATION_SUCCEEDED} from "../actions/authenticateUser";

const initialState = {
    calpersIds: [
        5600493427,
        6474994805,
        6452522440,
        5564535492,
        6632408185,
        4618604679,
        5826752269,
        3996179678,
        7302651964,
        1677401305,
        6827859055,
        3685610572,
        6581985123,
        3148148090
    ],
    guidMap: {
        7103503579: "dad08fde-0ac1-404a-ba8a-cc7c76d5810f",
        6632408185: "6632408185-guid",
        6581985123: "6581985123-guid",
        1226290314: "a3908aa7-c142-4752-85ea-3741cf28f75e",
        4618604679: "4618604679-guid",
        6452522440: "6452522440-guid",
        3685610572: "3685610572-guid",
        5564535492: "5564535492-guid",
        5600493427: "5600493427-guid",
        3996179678: "3996179678-guid",
        7302651964: "7302651964-guid",
        3148148090: "3148148090-guid",
        5826752269: "5826752269-guid",
        6827859055: "6827859055-guid",
        1677401305: "1677401305-guid",
        2640602392: "dbed1af6-0fc9-45dc-96a3-ab15aa05a7a2",
        6474994805: "6474994805-guid"
    },
    authToken: null,
    isAuthenticated: false
};
//@TODO: All fetches, create a seperate reducer for store?
export function authenticateUser(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case AUTHENTICATE_USER:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                authToken: action.token,
            })
        case AUTHENTICATATION_SUCCEEDED:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                authToken: action.payload.guid,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                payload: action.payload
            })
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should'nt use connect mapDispatchToProps like you are doing.
This callback is supposed to create or use functions that will dispatch an action.

For your case you can use it like that:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        authenticate: calpersId => authenticateUser(calpersId)(dispatch)
    }
}
```

And in your component have a function/method that handle the submit:

```
class Login extends Component {
  ...
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const calpersId = parseInt(e.target[0].value || e.target[1].value, 10) || 0;
    this.props.authenticate(calpersId)
  }
  ...
```

By the way a reducer is supposed to represent the state of an entity. An entity named autenticateUser is pretty ambigious. You should propably named it user. You should read more redux examples to really catch the concept that at first a bit complicated to understand. There are good videos on Youtube.

Comment: Got it. I looked at the code, and followed through to understand the concepts. Make's sense. Because I thought the logic should be in the container, and when the view gets replaced it should not be affected by any missing functions, variables etc.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was calling an action creator which did not exist, I simply needed to pass my dispatch to the handler, and let it handle the the event.

Login.js

```
import CONFIG from "../../../config";

import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import {authenticateUser} from "../../../actions/authenticateUser";

import Login from '../../../components/views/login/Login'

function handleSubmit(e, dispatch) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let calpersId = parseInt(e.target[0].value || e.target[1].value, 10) || 0;
    dispatch(authenticateUser(calpersId))
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        authentication: state.authentication
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        handleSubmit: (e) => {handleSubmit(e, dispatch)}
    }
}

const LoginContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);

export default LoginContainer;
```

What is the proper way of doing this, I utillized bindActionCreators which yields the same result.